# why am I getting '4:00' when I'm trying to display time using the date function with php?

Tags: php, date, time

I am trying to display a time I have in my database. I managed to have it display a time in the correct format for what I need, but for some reason, it is only displaying '4:00' every time.

Here is my code:

```
date('g:i', strtotime($row['startTime']))
```

An example of I have the time displayed in my database is like this:  00:12:30

Why is it showing '4:00' every time?

Comment: What is the data type of the column? What do you get if you just echo $row['startTime']?

Comment: hang on...if the date is *stored* as `00:12:30` and you want to display the hours (g) and minutes (i), why not simply `echo substr($dateText,0,5)` where `$dateText = $row['startTime'];`?

Comment: It's a time datatype. When I simply echo $row['startTime'], nothing shows up, its bizarre

Comment: Could I ask you to do two things? First: add the (relevant) details from "DESCRIBE *tablename*;" and secondly: show a sample of the data contained therein. I'm curious as to why `echo $row['startTime'];` does nothing, and wonder if the underlying data is...somehow other than you expect it to be.

Comment: Has anything worked; is the problem resolved? Are there new devlopments?

Comment: I forgot to include the columns I needed within my query! I am such an idiot. Thanks for all your time and efforts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strtotime expects a datetime format ... you should do

```
date('g:i', strtotime('01 January 2009 ' . $row['startTime']))
```

Comment: check that $row['startTime'] has a value, since it sounds likes its empty

Answer (score 1):

Whats the underlying database, and what datatype does the startTime column have? Peering at the closest php code I have, `strtoime` works fine with a DATETIME representation in the DB (MySQL).

Comment: the startTime column is a time datatype

Answer (score 1):

**strtotime** converts a date time string to a Unix timestamp.

Perhaps your $row['startTime'] doesn't qualify as a date time string.

None of the examples [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) discussed a date time string which did not include a date.

The link also said that if strtotime is confused, it returns random results. I would add a few more format characters and see what else is returned.

Answer (score 1):

As noted the problem is the use of `strtotime()`. The following works on my machine, if it's of any use:

```
 $date_text = $row['startTime']; // assuming the format "00:12:30"
 list($hrs,$mins,$secs) = explode(":",$date_text); // in response to the question in the comments
 /* the explode() takes the string "00:12:30" and breaks into three components "00","12" and "30".
 these components are named, by their order in the array formed by explode(), as $hrs, $mins and $secs.
see: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
and: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php
 */

 echo "<p>" . date("g:i",mktime($hrs,$mins,$secs)) . "</p>";
```

Comment: where are the variables $hrs, $mins, and $secs coming from?